# Problem when programming an optimization problem with gurobi

Tags: python, optimization, gurobi

Hello :) this question may be a little long, but I'll try to make it as short as possible.

I have modeled an optimization problem, and now I'm trying to solve it by using Gurobi on Python as follows:

```
# We insert the problem data

T = 6 # Amount of days
C = 5 # Amount of clients

M = ['plastic', 'glass'] # Materials' list
C_p = [1, 2, 3] # Plastic-processing clients
C_v = [4, 5]    # Glass-processing clients

# Material amount which each client receives, each row is a client and each column a day
P_ct = [[35, 28, 25, 30, 53, 24],
        [27, 33, 29, 24, 45, 21],
        [39, 32, 31, 27, 38, 22],
        [40, 35, 48, 30, 18, 32],
        [48, 22, 44, 37, 21, 31]]

q_p = 2 # Cost for throwing plastic
q_v = 3 # Cost for throwing glass
q_m = [2, 3] # List of costs for throwing each kind of material
Q = 50  # Fixed cost for changing the factory's configuration

A_c = [50, 45, 50, 65, 65] # Clients' warehouses' capacities
V = 130 # Total trucks' capacity
K = 250 # Factory's warehouse's capacity

U_p = 110 # Processing limit for plastic
U_v = 90  # Processing limit for glass
U_m = {'plastic': 110, 'glass': 90} # Dictionary with the limits

alpha = 1/2 # Alpha value

# Creating the model
model = gp.Model("RecyclingProblem")

# VARIABLES

# Material amount which is taken from client C on day T
R = model.addVars(C, T, lb=0, vtype=GRB.CONTINUOUS, name="R") 
# Material amount which is thrown from client C on day T
B = model.addVars(C, T, lb=0, vtype=GRB.CONTINUOUS, name="B")
# Material amount which is stored in the C client's warehouse on day T
G = model.addVars(C, T, lb=0, vtype=GRB.CONTINUOUS, name="G")
# Material amount which is processed by the factory on day T
H = model.addVars(M, T, lb=0, vtype=GRB.CONTINUOUS, name="H")  
# Material amount which is thrown from the factory on day T
V = model.addVars(M, T, lb=0, vtype=GRB.CONTINUOUS, name="V")  
# Material amount which is stored on the factory's warehouse on day T
J = model.addVars(M, T, lb=0, vtype=GRB.CONTINUOUS, name="J") 

# Binary which determines if the factory processes the M material on day T
X = model.addVars(M, T, vtype=GRB.BINARY, name="X") 
# Binary which determines if the factory changes the configuration on day T
Y = model.addVars(T, vtype=GRB.BINARY, name="Y")
# Binary which determines if the client C processes the M material
Z = model.addVars(M, T, vtype=GRB.BINARY, name="Z")   

# OBJECTIVE FUNCTION: to minimize the total costs
objective = sum(sum((q_p * Z[c, 0] + q_v * Z[c, 1]) * B[c,t] for c in range(C)) + alpha * sum(q_p * V[m,t] for m in M) + Q * Y[t] for t in range(T))

# Problem inicialization
model.setObjective(objective, GRB.MINIMIZE)

# Restrictions
# (1) In total, we can't take more material that the trucks' total capacity
model.addConstrs(gp.quicksum(R[c, t] for c in range(C)) <= V for t in range(T))
# (2) The stored material in the warehouses can't exceed their capacities
model.addConstrs(gp.quicksum(G[c, t] for t in range(T)) <= A_c[c] for c in range(C))  # (client)
model.addConstrs(gp.quicksum(J[m, t] for m in M for t in range(T)) <= K)       # (factory)
# Starting point for (3) for clients
model.addConstrs(G[c, 0] == P_ct[c][0] - R[c, 0] - B[c, 0] for c in range(C))
# (3) Definition of what is stored
for c in range(C): # clients
  for t in range(1,T):
    model.addConstr(G[c, t] == P_ct[c][t] - R[c, t] - B[c, t])
model.addConstrs(J[m,t] == - H[m,t] - V[m,t] + gp.quicksum(R[c, t] for c in range(C)) for t in range(T) for m in M) # factory  
# Starting point for (4)
model.addConstrs(J[m, 0] == gp.quicksum(R[c, 0] for c in range(C)) - H[m, 0] - V[m, 0] for m in M)
# (4) To restrict the material amount which is taken from the clients
for c in range(C):
  for t in range(1, T):
    model.addConstrs(R[c,t] <= gp.quicksum(G[c, t2] for t2 in range(1, t-1)) + P_ct[c][t])
# (5) Processing limit
model.addConstrs(H[m,t] <= U_m[m] for m in M for t in range(T))
# (6) We can only process one material per day
model.addConstrs(gp.quicksum(X[m, t] for m in M) <= 1 for t in range(T))

# Solving the model
model.optimize()

# Showing the solution
if model.status == GRB.OPTIMAL:
    print("Found optimal solution:")
    print(f"Objective value: {model.objVal}")
    print("Variables' values:")
    for var in model.getVars():
        print(f"{var.varName}: {var.x}")
else:
    print("An optimal solution can't be found.")
```

The thing is, as I try to run the code, both the objective function and the restrictions return errors. With the code I just copy-pasted I get this error in the objective function:

**KeyError: (0, 0)**

Then if I change the objective function with (which is not complete enough for my model, but I was trying to check if, at least, the restrictions were working):

`objective = sum(sum(q_p * B[c,t] for c in range(C)) + Q * Y[t] for t in range(T))`

I get this error for my first restriction:

**TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'gurobipy.LinExpr' and 'tupledict'**

Then, I try to keep going so I put a # besides the first restriction for checking out if the second one works, and I get this error for the second line of restriction (2):

**KeyError: 'Missing constraint index'**

So what I guess is that some variables may be not well defined (I mean not well programmed) but I can't find the mistakes, I have been hours trying to do so and I can't :(

Thanks in advance

PS: I would try to show the original model I wrote but stack overflow doesn't support math equations so I think it wouldn't be that helpful anyways.

Answer (score 0):

In the first part of your code, you are defining `T` to be a plain, old, simple integer:

```
T = 6 # Amount of days
```

So when you do this:

```
Z = model.addVars(M, T, vtype=GRB.BINARY, name="Z")
```

Z gets whatever `M` is and just 6 for `T` ... Make sense?

So when you do this:

```
objective = sum(sum((q_p * Z[c, 0] + q_v * Z[c, 1]) * B[c,t] for c in range(C)) + alpha * sum(q_p * V[m,t] for m in M) + Q * Y[t] for t in range(T))
```

the values for `t` are nonsense because you have basically declared `Z` to be indexed by `t` ∈ {6} and you are summing over `t` ∈ {1, 2, ..., 6}

So, in the first part of your model, redefine `T`:

```
T = list(range(6))
```

and then just use `T` instead of `range(t)` in your objective

**Then do all the same for `C`**

Answer (score 0):

In addition, to @airsquid comments, 2 corrections :

1. for 2nd restriction, you have written:

```
model.addConstrs(gp.quicksum(J[m, t] for m in M for t in range(T)) <= K)
```

it's basically a single constraint, as K is just an integer, so you should use just `model.addConstr` like below:

```
model.addConstr(gp.quicksum(J[m, t] for m in M for t in range(T)) <= K)
```

that's why you were getting `missing constraint index error`

2. for 4th restriction, you again need to use `model.addConstr` since with a for loop you are adding one constraint at a time. Do it as follows:

```
for c in range(C):
  for t in range(1, T):
    model.addConstr(R[c,t] <= gp.quicksum(G[c, t2] for t2 in range(1, t-1)) + P_ct[c][t])
```